# Display error message from Servlet to JSP page without reloading the page

Tags: java, html, validation, jsp, servlets

I have an HTML form for user login on a JSP document and I send the input of the user to a Servlet, check the password against a database then redirect the user to a new page if it's correct or show an error message on the page "Incorrect Password" of incorrect.
I want the error message to appear on the same page as the form just below the Password input field. I have tried the code below but it still redirects me to a new page where it displays only the "Incorrect Password" message.
Is there any other way on how to do it?
Thank you in advance.

//SERVLET CODE

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

            //Some code to check if the password matches the one in the DB and redirects to another page.

                } else {

                String text = "Incorrect Password!";

               response.setContentType("text/plain"); 
               response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); 
               response.getWriter().write(text); 


                }

            }

        }
```

//JSP PAGE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script>
$('#sButton').click(function() {
       $.post('UserServlet', function(responseText) {
              $('#msg').text(responseText);   
           });
     });
 </script>
<title>User Log in</title>
<%@ include file="PageHeader.html" %>
</head>
<body>
<form action = "SomeServlet" method="POST">
<h3 >Enter detailsto Sign In</h3><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="email" required><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" required><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in">
<div style="color:red" id="msg"></div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message should appear on this same page as I understand but it just opens a new page showing only the message and not the html form.

Comment: you haven't made any ajax calls that's why

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: Well it doesn't look like you've even tried. Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4112686/5360672

Comment: I read the link that you sent but I still am not clear on how to edit my code so it can work. I am new to all this so if you could help me so I can understand it better. Am I missing something in my code or is it all wrong?

Comment: Follow the examples and try it out. Specifically the first one. I'm not writing the code for you but i can help you when I've seen you've made an effort

Comment: okay thank you for the suggestion. I will try it out and then get back to you

Comment: You can look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52972468/save-form-data-after-redirecting-servlet-error-message-to-jsp) for some help